# Powershell - all user-accounts on a PC and their settings

Tags: powershell, user-accounts

We have some PCs in our domain, and usually a PC has its owner. But of course sometimes users login to another PC - Jim is on Jack's PC, Jack works on Sue's PC. And usually they are defined as "Users", but sometimes there are changes: Jim is defined as Administrator on his PC, Sue is defined as User and as Remotedesktop-user on her PC, and Jack is only Remoteuser on his own PC but Admin on Mike's PC.

You see - that smell's a little bit like chaos ...

How can I make a list for every PC which User has which rights?
(Can be started from the PC itself, a luxury solution would check it centralized from AD server or something else.)

Are there existing solutions?
Or will it be a complex coding (beyond my beginner level ...)?

regards!

Comment: You can't.  Your network Group Policies allows anybody to log into any PC.  The best you can do is to check the c:\Userrs folder to see who already connected to each machine.

Comment: It appears that profiles. including a SID and home directory, are in the registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.